# what are the correct imports to use for apache commons for MultiValuedMap using ArrayListValuedHashMap

Tags: java, import, apache-commons

thank you in advance, much appreciated!

I'm trying to use the apache commons MultiValuedMap implementation. but, I can't seem to import the correct packages???

here are my imports:

```
package com.ge.digital.fleet.dataservice.impl.db;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;
//import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiValueMap;

import com.ge.digital.fleet.dataservice.RefDataServiceInvalidDataException;
import com.ge.digital.fleet.dataservice.RefDataServiceUnavailableException;

public class RefDatabase {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RefDatabase.class);

    private MultiValuedMap<String, String> associationsMap = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
//      private Map<String,Collection<String>> map = associationsMap.asMap();
```

my POM.xml has commons dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

but it throws compile error

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\212555427\devel\workspaces\jbds\iprcsmartsignal\fleet-predix-new\fleet.mt1.dataserviceimpl\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\fleet\dataservice\impl\db\RefDatabase.java:[11,53] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ArrayListValuedHashMap
[ERROR]   location: interface MultiValuedMap
[ERROR] C:\Users\212555427\devel\workspaces\jbds\iprcsmartsignal\fleet-predix-new\fleet.mt1.dataserviceimpl\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\fleet\dataservice\impl\db\RefDatabase.java:[21,62] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ArrayListValuedHashMap
[ERROR]   location: class RefDatabase
```

I've tried several combinations of imports with no success.
thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that this combination works, I'm not sure if this is correct or not tho?

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
//import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;
//import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiValueMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.*;
//import org.apache.commons.collections4.*;
//import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap.*;
//import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.*;
```